# Error "no overload matches this call" in navigation.navigate

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack

Im making an app and got to the part of navigating through the screens,and this line : navigation.navigate('CreateAccount'); seems to have an error, specifically when calling " Create Account", saying that no overload matches this call, but i couldnt spot the mistake so i dont know what to do.
Heres the code:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Dimensions, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform } from 'react-native';

import abacatezinImg from '../assets/abacatezin.png';

export function LoginScreen(){
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    function handleCreate(){
        navigation.navigate('CreateAccount');
    }

    return(
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        
                <Image source={abacatezinImg} style={styles.abacatezin}/>
                
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                    Faça seu login para começar
                </Text>

                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Email"/>
                <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Senha"/>

                <TouchableOpacity >
                    <Text style={styles.botao1}>
                        Entrar
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleCreate}>
                    <Text style={styles.botao2}>  
                        Criar conta
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <Text style={styles.esquecenha}>
                    Esqueci minha senha
                </Text>
         
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor: '#FAFFF9',
    },
    abacatezin:{
        marginTop: 58,
        width: 30,
        height: 36,
    },
    title:{
        fontSize: 34,
        fontWeight: '600',
        lineHeight: 42,
        marginTop: 45,
    },
    input:{
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#7E9F70', 
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        width: 327,
        height: 56,
        borderRadius: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        textAlign: 'left',
        padding: 11,
        marginTop: 32,
        marginBottom: -12,
    },
    botao1:{
        backgroundColor: '#7E9F70',
        width: 327,
        height: 53,
        borderRadius: 37,
        padding: 12,
        paddingHorizontal: 121,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '700',
        marginTop: 44,
    },
    botao2:{
        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        width: 327,
        height: 53,
        borderRadius: 37,
        padding: 12,
        paddingHorizontal: 105,
        borderWidth: 1,
        color: '#7E9F70',
        borderColor: '#7E9F70',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: '700',
        marginTop: 14,
    },
    esquecenha:{
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '400',
        lineHeight: 27,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 34,
    }
});
```

And the stack.routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { LoginScreen } from '../pages/LoginScreen';
import { CreateAccount } from '../pages/CreateAccount';

const stackRoutes = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
    <stackRoutes.Navigator
        /*headerMode="none"*/
        screenOptions={{cardStyle: {backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, headerShown: false}}
    >

        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="LoginScreen"
            component={LoginScreen}
        />
        <stackRoutes.Screen
            name="CreateAccount"
            component={CreateAccount}
        />

    </stackRoutes.Navigator>
)

export default AppRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot use `<NavigationContainer />` [Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/)

And also change `stackRoutes` on `StackRoutes`. JSX component should start from big letter.

Comment: Where exactly should be the container? I tried with it wrapping whats in the return as the docs says but i still got the error

Comment: ```export default function App() {
return (
<NavigationContainer>
<AppRoutes />
</NavigationContainer>)
}```
This how it should look.